# Trouble Checking if has value and is visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, coldfusion

Have Several variables listed in an array.

```
<cfset inputs = ["from","subject","custnumber","amount","password"] />
```

have to test each variable to see if two things are true, its visible, and the field is full or pass an error.

```
function formcheck() {
thiserror = 0;
<cfloop array="#inputs#" index="thisinput"> 
    if (document.getElementById('#thisinput#' + 'real').value == '') AND $('##' +'#thisinput#' + 'container').css('display') != 'none') {
        thiserror = 1;          
        $("###thisinput#errortip").fadeIn(300);
        }

</cfloop>
```

keep getting an "missing ; before statement error"

full code as is :

```
<cfoutput>
function formcheck() {
thiserror = 0;
<cfloop array="#inputs#" index="thisinput"> 
    if (document.getElementById('#thisinput#' + 'real').value == '' AND $('##' +'#thisinput#' + 'container').css('display') != 'none') {
        thiserror = 1;          
        $("###thisinput#errortip").fadeIn(300);
        }

</cfloop>
    if (thiserror == 0) {
        load('#targeturl#','#targetdiv#',
            <cfloop array="#inputs#" index="thisinput">
            '&#thisinput#=' + document.getElementById('#thisinput#' + 'real').value +
            </cfloop>
            ''
            )


    }
}
```

Comment: get rid of the `)` after `value == ''`

Comment: just realized that, made the tweak but still receiving error.

Comment: Do you have a closing tag for your function? Also, please post the _exact_ code that is generating the error.

Comment: as a bit of style advice, don't generate JS code, instead generate data in JS format. By mixing data and code, it gets much harder to debug. Make a JS function which takes an array of element names, then use CF to generate the array. You can then test it within the browser without involving CF at all. When you're happy it works, use CF to generate the list.

Comment: Can you post the actual generated JavaScript code from the page source? Also when first setting `thiserror` you should probably use `var thiserror = 0` to keep it local to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the only error in your Javascript - but I am quite sure that 'AND' is not Javascript operator. As far as I know, 'AND' only works in ColdFusion itself.
Replace it with the Javascript equivalent '&&' and your code should work.

Furthermore, you really have a missing semicolon: your load()- function lacks of it.

Comment: it did take AND and solved the problem thanks for the input ^.^